# regexp replace to replace the second special character from the last in a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to replace last 2 special characters in my string .I tried the below options

It replaces the last special character from my string

```
select regexp_replace(trim('Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.'),'([^0-9A-Za-z]+)$','') from dual;
```

It replaces all the special characters in my string

```
select regexp_replace(trim('Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.'),'[^0-9A-Za-z]','') from dual;
```

I need a function that replaces only the last 2 special characters in the string.

```
e.g 1 Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.      should be 
      Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-SR  

e.g 2 Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr      should be 
      HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr   

e.g 3 Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk       should be 
      Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk
```

Comment: you should explain the logic you are looking for. why is in the first string `-`is not replaced but in the second

Comment: in the first example the last 2 special characters are dots. So only those 2 must be removed.In the second the last 2 special characters are - and those 2 are removed

Answer (score 2):

How about this? See comments within the code:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.' from dual union all
  3     select 'Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr' from dual union all
  4     select 'Lenore&BillAlexander''35/Faulk' from dual union all
  5     select 'This-is#just)an_example'        from dual
  6    )
  7  select
  8    col,
  9    regexp_replace
 10      (col,
 11       '[^[:alnum:]]',                 -- replace non alphanumeric ...
 12       '',                             -- .. with an empty string
 13       -- starting at position calculated as position of ...
 14       regexp_instr(col,
 15                    '[^[:alnum:]]',    -- ... a non alphanumeric character
 16                    1,                 -- found from the beginning of the string
 17                    -- taking into account the last and previous to last occurence
 18                    -- calculated by regexp_count which finds number of non alphanumerics
 19                    greatest(regexp_count(col, '[^[:alnum:]]') - 1, 1)),
 20       0) result
 21  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-S.R.  Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-SR
Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr
Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk  Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk
This-is#just)an_example        This-is#justanexample

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this option as well as REVERSE in my plsql block

Comment: You're welcome. Just be warned: REVERSE is undocumented and Oracle might remove it from any future database version so your code won't work. Besides, it reverses bytes, not characters do it won't work properly in multybyte character sets.

Comment: considering that many companies take a long time to switch to new versions and oracle still has not removed the function, I would say no risk no fun :)
In 10 years you can still change it, but what will happen in so many years, who knows. But you should take the most optimal solution.

Comment: Well, @hotfix, the same goes for WM_CONCAT. It is undocumented but it worked. Oracle removed it from 12c onward (true, replaced it with LISTAGG which is "official" and documented). The same might happen with REVERSE - Oracle will remove it and provide its replacement, but developers (who used REVERSE) will have to fix their code. But, yes - if someone stays on 11g *forever*, no worries (apart from function's restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better solution for the problem, but this one works

```
with str as(
select 'Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.' as txt from dual union all
select 'Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr' as txt from dual union all
select 'Lenore&BillAlexander''35/Faulk' as txt from dual 
)
select REVERSE(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(REVERSE(t.txt),'[^A-Za-z0-9]','',1,1),'[^A-Za-z0-9]','',1,1)) as new_str
from str t;
```

first use a reverse funtion , then remove the first occurrence twice and then reverse  again

> ```
> TXT                            | REVERSE_TXT                    | NEW_STR                     
> :----------------------------- | :----------------------------- | :---------------------------
> Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-S.R.  | .R.S-94'renloBeilasoR/notfilC  | Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-SR 
> Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr | rtordyH-yparehtordyH-xrowordyH | HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr
> Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk  | kluaF/53'rednaxelAlliB&eroneL  | Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25c9f47cde068571cfe57432cb3e298a)*

Comment: Thank you . But i still think we can achieve this without reverse.

Comment: select regexp_replace(trim('Hydroworx Hydrotherapy Hydrotr'),' ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$', '\1\2') from dual; This syntax removed last 2 spaces from a string. The same did not work for special characters.

Comment: That's *cheating* :), using an undocumented function!

Comment: @Littlefoot  _no cheat no life_ :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use backreferences? Further information can be found on the page for the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) function.
The `CROSS APPLY` clause of the [`SELECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) statement was used to move the calculation of the `cleansed_s` "variable" into the `JOIN` area and only specify it once.
The `x` in the `match_parameter` parameter of the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function allows you to ignore whitespace character in a pattern.
Whitespace characters were included in the pattern using the [alternative quoting mechanism for string literals](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html) to improve a readability. But, given that Oracle supports [some commonly used PERL regular expression operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-086CC1C0-E804-4E8D-9F0F-1925F325EC0C__CHDDGICJ), it's possible to write the call of the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function more briefly: `regexp_replace(s, '(\W(\w*))?\W(\w*)$', '\2\3')`.

```sql
with
  t as(
    select
      'Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.' as s,
      'Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-SR' as expected_result
    from dual union all
    select
       'Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr',
       'HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr'
    from dual union all
    select
      'Lenore&BillAlexander''35/Faulk',
      'Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk'
    from dual union all
    select 'foo', 'foo' from dual union all
    select 'foo&bar', 'foobar' from dual union all
    select '..', '' from dual
)
select
  t.*,
  ca.*,
  case
    when t.expected_result is null or
         t.expected_result = ca.cleansed_s then 'passed'
    else 'not passed'
  end as test_result
from t
cross apply (
  select regexp_replace(s,
           q'% ([^[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]]*))?
               [^[:alnum:]]([[:alnum:]]*)$ %',
           '\2\3', 1, 0, 'x') as cleansed_s from dual
) ca;
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
|               S                |       EXPECTED_RESULT        |          CLEANSED_S          | TEST_RESULT |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
| Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-S.R.  | Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-SR  | Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-SR  | passed      |
| Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr | HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr | HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr | passed      |
| Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk  | Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk  | Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk  | passed      |
| foo                            | foo                          | foo                          | passed      |
| foo&bar                        | foobar                       | foobar                       | passed      |
| ..                             |                              |                              | passed      |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55dc52408b16e6aeb3d0171815653417).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way of looking at it.  Use REGEXP_REPLACE() to group the different parts of the string, then only display the groups you want.  Here the regex specifically groups the last 2 non-alphnumeric characters with optional strings of any characters before, after, or in between but when they occur at the end of the string.  Replace all of that with groups 1, 3 and 5 which is all but the 2 non-alpha-numeric characters.

```
with test(id, col) as (
  select 1, 'Clifton/RosalieBolner''49-S.R.' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Lenore&BillAlexander''35/Faulk' from dual union all
  select 4, 'This-is#just)an_example'        from dual union all
  select 5, 'Test line 5 special *chars'     from dual union all
  select 6, 'TTest line 6^char'              from dual union all
  select 7, 'Thislineisoneword'              from dual union all
  select 8, '^^Thislineisonewordtoo'         from dual union all  
  select 9, NULL                             from dual
)
select id, col before,
  regexp_replace(col, '^(.*)?([^[:alnum:]])(.*)?([^[:alnum:]])(.*)?$', '\1\3\5') after
from test
order by id;


        ID BEFORE                         AFTER                         
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1 Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-S.R.  Clifton/RosalieBolner'49-SR   
         2 Hydroworx-Hydrotherapy-Hydrotr HydroworxHydrotherapyHydrotr  
         3 Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk  Lenore&BillAlexander35Faulk   
         4 This-is#just)an_example        This-is#justanexample         
         5 Test line 5 special *chars     Test line 5 specialchars      
         6 TTest line 6^char              TTest line6char               
         7 Thislineisoneword              Thislineisoneword             
         8 ^^Thislineisonewordtoo         Thislineisonewordtoo          
         9                                                              

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and detail explanation. If i want to keep apostrophe as well as alpha numeric . how do i include that?

Comment: It already does.  Groups 2 and 4 that get removed are a single NON-alpha-numeric character.  If I am missing something, please update with a before/after example to clarify.

Comment: in the 3rd example i want to keep the apostrophe and remove the ampersand.Like from Lenore&BillAlexander'35/Faulk to LenoreBillAlexander'35Faulk